# Getting 'No adapter attached; skipping layout' in kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview

I am not able to figure out what is wrong that adapter is not attached, i'm trying to build an app which shows name of medicines in recyclerview from database file present in assets/databases/ folder.

Here is MainActivity.kt

```
import android.app.Activity
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView


class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    //private lateinit var dataModel: DataModel
    private lateinit var recyclerView: RecyclerView
    private lateinit var dataBaseHelper: DataBaseHelper
    private lateinit var drugs: ArrayList<DataModel>

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        val myDatabase = DataBaseHelper(this).readableDatabase
        val cursor = myDatabase.query("drugindex", arrayOf("drug"), null, null, null, null, null)


        dataBaseHelper = DataBaseHelper(this)
        val recyclerView : RecyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerView)
        recyclerView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true)


    }

    private fun displayuser() {
        drugs = ArrayList<DataModel>()
        recyclerView.adapter = MyAdapter(drugs)
    }

}
```

Here is MyAdapter.kt

```
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.widget.TextView
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView

class MyAdapter(private val drugs: List<DataModel>) : RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter.DrugViewHolder>() {
    class ViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView){
        val textView : TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.txt)
    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): DrugViewHolder {
        val view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.recyclerviewitems, parent, false)
        return DrugViewHolder(view)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: DrugViewHolder, position: Int) {
        holder.bind(drugs[position])
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return drugs.size
    }

    inner class DrugViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {
        fun bind(drug: DataModel) {
            itemView.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.txt).text = drug.drug_name
        }
    }
}
```

Here is DataBaseHelper.kt

```
import android.content.Context
import android.content.SharedPreferences
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper
import java.io.File
import java.io.FileOutputStream

class DataBaseHelper (private val context: Context) : SQLiteOpenHelper(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION) {

    private val preferences: SharedPreferences = context.getSharedPreferences(
        "${context.packageName}.database_versions",
        Context.MODE_PRIVATE
    )

    private fun installedDatabaseIsOutdated(): Boolean {
        return preferences.getInt(DATABASE_NAME, 0) < DATABASE_VERSION
    }

    private fun writeDatabaseVersionInPreferences() {
        preferences.edit().apply {
            putInt(DATABASE_NAME, DATABASE_VERSION)
            apply()
        }
    }

    private fun installDatabaseFromAssets() {
        val inputStream = context.assets.open("$ASSETS_PATH/$DATABASE_NAME.sqlite3")

        try {
            val outputFile = File(context.getDatabasePath(DATABASE_NAME).path)
            val outputStream = FileOutputStream(outputFile)

            inputStream.copyTo(outputStream)
            inputStream.close()

            outputStream.flush()
            outputStream.close()
        } catch (exception: Throwable) {
            throw RuntimeException("The $DATABASE_NAME database couldn't be installed.", exception)
        }
    }

    @Synchronized
    private fun installOrUpdateIfNecessary() {
        if (installedDatabaseIsOutdated()) {
            context.deleteDatabase(DATABASE_NAME)
            installDatabaseFromAssets()
            writeDatabaseVersionInPreferences()
        }
    }

    override fun getWritableDatabase(): SQLiteDatabase {
        throw RuntimeException("The $DATABASE_NAME database is not writable.")
    }

    override fun getReadableDatabase(): SQLiteDatabase {
        installOrUpdateIfNecessary()
        return super.getReadableDatabase()
    }

    override fun onCreate(db: SQLiteDatabase?) {
        // Nothing to do
    }

    override fun onUpgrade(db: SQLiteDatabase?, oldVersion: Int, newVersion: Int) {
        // Nothing to do
    }

    companion object {
        const val DATABASE_NAME = "myDB"
        const val DATABASE_VERSION = 1
        const val ASSETS_PATH = "databases"
    }

}
```

Here is DataModel.kt

```
data class DataModel(
    val drug_name : String,
        )
```

I tried various guides online but none of them solves this issue, i am expecting an output with lists of names

**Now I have updated Mainactivity and adapter and errors are gone, but nothing is visible in recyclerview or textview**

**Updated MainActivity.kt**

```
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var dataModel: DataModel
    //private lateinit var recyclerView: RecyclerView
    private lateinit var dataBaseHelper: DataBaseHelper
    private lateinit var drugs: ArrayList<DataModel>

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        val recyclerView : RecyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerView)
        val myDatabase = DataBaseHelper(this).readableDatabase
        val cursor = myDatabase.query("drugindex", arrayOf("drug_name"), null, null, null, null, null)


        dataBaseHelper = DataBaseHelper(this)
        recyclerView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true)
        recyclerView.adapter = MyAdapter(ArrayList<DataModel>())


    }
}
```

**Updated MyAdapter.kt**

```
    import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.widget.TextView
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView

class MyAdapter(private val drugs: List<DataModel>) : RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter.DrugViewHolder>() {

    class ViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView){
       private val textView : TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.txt)
    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): DrugViewHolder {
        val view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.recyclerviewitems, parent, false)
        return DrugViewHolder(view)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: DrugViewHolder, position: Int) {
        holder.bind(drugs[position])
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return drugs.size
    }

    class DrugViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {
        fun bind(drug: DataModel) {
            itemView.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.txt).text = drug.drug_name
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Where did you set the adapter to the recycler view? You forgot to set it (in your case is a call to `displayuser` function). Your log is saying the recycler view has no adapter, so it will skip its layout phase

Comment: I did remove the whole  'private fun displayuser() {..'  now, when i put the 'recyclerview.adapter = MyAdapter' it underlines MyAdapter and everything i put after it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The below code should work for you.

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

private lateinit var dataModel: DataModel
private lateinit var recyclerView: RecyclerView
private lateinit var dataBaseHelper: DataBaseHelper
private lateinit var drugs: ArrayList<DataModel>

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    val myDatabase = DataBaseHelper(this).readableDatabase
    val cursor = myDatabase.query("drugindex", arrayOf("drug"), null, null, null, null, null)


    dataBaseHelper = DataBaseHelper(this)
    var recyclerView : RecyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerView)
    recyclerView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true)
    recyclerView.adapter = MyAdapter(arrayListOf<Drugs>())
}
```

}

Comment: Thanks, it solves the problem with Adapter
Now the problem is with the recyclerview not showing any data

Comment: For that you have to get the data from your databaseHelper as a list. That is a different problem as the question was about adapter issue. Please upvote if the main issue got reosolved.

Comment: Yes, I need 15 reputation to vote it says, i'm new so i just checked the answer

Answer (score 0):

This line in `onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?)` method

```
val recyclerView : RecyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerView)
```

remove `val` from here as RecyclerView object already declare as `var` on top of class

```
 private lateinit var recyclerView: RecyclerView
```

what happening is, It creates two different object.  One with recyclerview reference and other recyclerview object is not initialized. You are passing adapter to uninitialized recyclerview  object

Comment: I tried builds with both these lines together and alone, but getting same error.
Also 'val' or 'var' is required to avoid any red underlined texts in code 'recyclerView : RecyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerView)'